# Is it possible to reject empty answers from a custom prompt?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get users' names just as they open a spreadsheet. Is there a way to reject the input if this is empty?

I am not sure how to go about this. What I am trying to get at is to copy the spreadsheet data and paste it on another spreadsheet adding a column that repeats the user name on each row.

This is the prompt code without the input rejection.

```
function askName() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  //Display prompt.
  var result = ui.prompt(
    'Start the form!',
    'Enter your name:',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    ui.alert('Your name is ' + text + '.');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('I did not get that.');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You closed the dialogue');
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get the entire issue, but if it's just about checking if the response is not blank, why not just add a test on `text == ""`, and if true, interrupt / restart the process?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to put your prompt in a "while" loop so as long as the name isn't valid (in our case, just not blank), the prompt will appear again (with, in this example, an error alert in between). You could also decide to kill the function (`return ;`) if the name is blank, and have the user start the process again.

```
function askName() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  //Display prompt.

  var result; 
  var text = "";

  while (text == ""){
    result = ui.prompt(
      'Start the form!',
      'Enter your name:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

    // Process user's response.
    var button = result.getSelectedButton();
    text = result.getResponseText();
    if (text == "") ui.alert('Name cannot be blank');
    else if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
      // User clicked "OK".
      ui.alert('Your name is ' + text + '.');
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
      // User clicked "Cancel".
      ui.alert('I did not get that.');
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
      // User clicked X in the title bar.
      ui.alert('You closed the dialogue');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot!